# How to avoid multiple if statements checking if property is null in typescript

Tags: angular, typescript

I'm curious if there's a better way or approach to writing the following code.

```
    private buildQueryParams(filterData: BaseFilterModel | RegistrationFilterModel): HttpParams {
    let params = new HttpParams();
    if (filterData) {
      if (filterData.regionId) {
        params = params.set('regionId', filterData.regionId.toString());
      }
      if (filterData.facilityId) {
        params = params.set('facilityId', filterData.facilityId.toString());
      }
      if (filterData.dept1 && filterData.dept1.id) {
        params = params.set('dept1', filterData.dept1.id.toString());
      }
      if (filterData.dept2 && filterData.dept2.id) {
        params = params.set('dept2', filterData.dept2.id.toString());
      }
      if (filterData.role && filterData.role !== 'All') {
        params = params.set('role', filterData.role);
      }
      if ((<RegistrationFilterModel>filterData).registrationDate) {
        params = params.set('registrationDate', (<RegistrationFilterModel>filterData).registrationDate.toString());
      }
      if ((<RegistrationFilterModel>filterData).activeStatus
        && (<RegistrationFilterModel>filterData).activeStatus !== ActiveStatus.All) {
        params = params.set('activeStatus', (<RegistrationFilterModel>filterData).activeStatus.toString());
      }
    }

    return params;
  }
```

What this is basically doing is creating the parameters for a http request based on an object (filterData) that has these set values. We use this object for multiple endpoints with similar but slightly different parameters, so it goes through each one of these if statements to make sure the regionId, facilityId, ect. is not null.

Is there a better way to do this instead of having a list of if statements that could get larger and larger if we add more parameters.

Comment: You could make a delegator method to delegate what should be made instead of if else

Comment: I've never heard of a delegator method before, do you have any good explains I could read up on?

Comment: Look up strategy pattern or delegator pattern

Comment: You could create helper methods for common checks and assignments but as far as I can quickly see there are at least 3 variations. Direct check/assignment, a check on id with assignment, and a check on value with assignment. You would have to create 3 delegating methods or delegating method with if/else blocks..

Comment: Ideally they would approve https://github.com/tc39/proposal-optional-chaining but don't hold your breath.

Comment: This is perfectly fine code. The solutions put forth in the answers are overkill and make it less readable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could define a local function to do the actual setting with a test to avoid null or undefined (or empty string) and conversion to string where required. Something like:

```
private buildQueryParams(filterData: BaseFilterModel | RegistrationFilterModel): HttpParams {
 let params = new HttpParams();
 function setparam(name: string, value: number|string) {
   if (value) params = params.set(name, value.toString());
 }

 if (filterData) {
     setparam('regionId', filterData.regionId);
     setparam('facilityId', filterData.facilityId);
     setparam('dept1',  filterData.dept1 && filterData.dept1.id);
     setparam('dept2', filterData.dept2 && filterData.dept2.id);
     if (filterData.role != 'All') {
       setparam('role', filterData.role);
     }
     setparam('registrationDate', (<RegistrationFilterModel>filterData).registrationDate);
     if ((<RegistrationFilterModel>filterData).activeStatus !== ActiveStatus.All) {
       setparam('activeStatus', (<RegistrationFilterModel>filterData).activeStatus);
     }
 }

 return params;
}
```

The actual type for `value` should match the expected types, or could even be `any`.

Answer (score 1):

You can reduce some lines with:

```
 var fields = ['regionId','facilityId','dept1','dept2'];
  for (let field of fields) {
    if (filterData[field]){
        params = params.set(field, filterData[field].toString());
    }
  }
```

or manage each case with concrete strategy with strategy pattern.

Comment: Doesn't work for the `dept1`, `dept2` fields as they need to check one level deeper for the `id` attribute, but could work for the others.

Answer (score 0):

> Lodash is the way to go:

```js
var object = {
  'a': [{
    'b': {
      'c': 100
    },
    'd': 'MARKS'
  }]
};

console.log(_.get(object, ['a', '0', 'b', 'c']));
console.log(_.get(object, ['a', '0', 'd']).toLowerCase());    // Do operation on the object found
console.log(_.get(object, ['a', '0', 'foo'], 'granted'));     // Specify default value, if incorrect path
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.5/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

> Take a look at the documentation:

[Lodash Get](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.5#get)

> Explanation

1. It takes care of the multiple if cases within and if nothing is found, returns a default value
2. You can do whatever you want with the returned value, make it lower, or upper, or convert to string
3. There are multiple syntaxes possible with lodash, take a look at the documentation for them

Answer (score 0):

More object oriented way is do something like this.

```
enum ActiveStatus {
  ALL
}

class Department {
  constructor(private _id: number){}
  public toString() {
    return this._id.toString();
  }
}

class Role {
  private _name: "ALL";

  public toString() {
    return this._name == "ALL" ? "" : this._name;
  }
}

class FilterData {

  constructor(
    private _regionId: number,
    private _facilityId: number,
    private _dep1: Department,
    private _dep2: Department,
    private _activeStatus: ActiveStatus
  ) {

  }

  public toHttpParams() {
    let params = new HttpParams();
    Object.keys(this).forEach((key) => {
      let value = this[key].toString();
      value && params.set(key.slice(1), value);
    });
    return params;
  }
}

let filterData = new FilterData(
  1,
  2,
  new Department(5),
  new Department(7),
  ActiveStatus.ALL
);

console.log(filterData.toHttpParams());
```

Comment: What does the ALL line in ActiveStatus mean?

Comment: Seems the same as in your code "((<RegistrationFilterModel>filterData).activeStatus !== ActiveStatus.All) ". It is not 100% working suggestion, but example of how to do OOP strucure.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the optional chaining operator **?**

> ```
> let x = foo?.bar.baz();
> ```

and the Nullish coalescing operator  **??**

> let x = foo ?? bar();

[Doc Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-7.html)